# how spl_autoload_register works internally

Tags: php, error-handling

what i know is spl_autoload_register function is lib function which takes callback function which gets executed when error 'file not found'(fatal) occurs while using new keyword and that include that specific class or rather file. 
so my question is how does it handle fatal error being on top of the code if suppose it can handle fatal error.
and my think of error or exception handle is you must know error or exception is that we must know before so that we can include this in the block try,throw, catch.
so my question is how does it catches error being on top of the code.
i am beginner any help appreciated. 
thankyou

Comment: There probably isn't an error to begin with. When trying to use the class, it will see there is no such definition registered and call the callback. That's my guess anyway. You can look through the C code if you want to know for definite.

Comment: which c code, could u give any resource link? thankyou

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/623911f993f39ebbe75abe2771fc89faf6b15b9b/ext/spl/php_spl.c maybe

Comment: [This C code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/php_spl.c#L498) from the PHP interpreter. Looks like the interpreter uses exceptions based on whether the function is defined before calling the autoload callback. I'm hardly a C dev, though, so take a pound of salt with that

Comment: It might be getting run [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/99230784f5524f5387a8a6760bdaf9aa2eb91545/Zend/zend_execute_API.c#L827). Which looks like it loads if `zv = zend_hash_find(EG(class_table), lc_name);` is false, i.e. the class is unknown in the class_table. Then the function is called on L916, then it checks the class_table again?